# get documents irrespective of years in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

### I want to get all documents on 8 Dec irrespective of years. I have tried two queries but both fails, Is there any way to calculate this?

First Query

```
GET /my_index/my_type/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "range": {
                  "myDate": {
                     "gte": "12-08",
                     "lte": "12-08",
                     "format": "MM-dd"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Second Query

```
GET /my_index/my_type/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "match": {
                  "mydate": "12-08"
                  }               
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think that will be easily possible. DateTime datatypes are actually just long numbers. The range query will also transform the defined input into a number. Example: now -> 1497541939892. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html for more information - specifically this:

> Internally, dates are converted to UTC (if the time-zone is specified) and stored as a long number representing milliseconds-since-the-epoch.

With that in mind, you would have to subtract 1 (or x) years (in milliseconds) for every subquery. That doesn't sound practical.

I think your best bet would be, to additionally index the day and month - and maybe year as well - separately. Then you would be able to query just by month/day, which would be integer values. I don't know if that is easily done in your case, but I really have no other idea right now.